# Ip not ping for vagrant homestead

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

I am getting problem when i open my project app url in browser then its 
 getting timeout. if i open ip address also then also timeout. 
I have already installed vagrat , virtual box on my mac machine. 
I am following these steps

- First clone my project in `tony/project`
- Cd project
- composer install
- vagrant init laravel/homestead
- php vendor/bin/homestead make
- vagrant up
- when i run vagrant ssh then it goes to ubantu

  I have also include my homestead.yaml file ip or app name in /etc/hosts.
  Now when i open app name like `project.app` or ip like `92.168.10.10` then its not run.
  When i open my virtual machine and there is also a box running like project_default_44443334_2323. 
  Please le me know what is issue . where i am wrong. please help

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your computer and try again in a browser:

```
192.168.10.10
192.168.10.10:8000
```

If it still doesn't work, try to temporarily turn off firewall and antivirus software, including Windows built in firewall and try again.

Comment: i have reboot my mac but not fix

Comment: i am new to mac and not know that ip is config or not?

Comment: https://kb.iu.edu/d/aozg - try to turn off buil in firewall (if you do not have any additional antivirus or firewall software).

Comment: ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
hostname: project
name: project
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: "/Users/tony/project"
      to: "/home/vagrant/project"

sites:
    - map: moblife.app
      to: "/home/vagrant/project/public"

databases:
    - homestead

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp

Comment: Config file looks fine, do you see your project files when using SSH (in Ubuntu, inside VM)?

Comment: `vagrant ssh`, `cd your/project`. `ls` shows nothing? Also, try to run `vagrant provision` command.

Comment: when i run cd project_name then  : no such file found

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/xq2yg73ra04biej/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-25%20at%201.38.35%20pm.png?oref=e&n=558692351  after ssh command

Comment: Did you run `bash init.sh` to create `Homestead.yaml`? Did you try to run `vagrant provision`? It seems vagrnat doesn't map folders.

Comment: when i run bash init.sh then it show init.sh not found

Comment: when i run 'ls /' in ssh then it list https://www.dropbox.com/s/nzadd7xihio9pu0/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-25%20at%201.59.42%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: You need to run `bash init.sh` on your Mac, not inside the VM. It will create `Homestead.yaml` and will put it into `/Users/tony/.homestead`. That's the `Homestead.yaml` which Vagrant is using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110113/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-alexey-mezenin).